# FFMPEG preset is not found? Linux Cent OS 6

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I ran this command

```
ffmpeg -i v-16418145218d8d7abdaabec46beb22ecffd2f5d1625.flv -y -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 160k -vcodec libx264 -vpre iPod640 -vpre slow -f mp4 -threads 0 OUTPUT.mp4
```

Got this response:

```
[flv @ 0x10ff670]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
Input #0, flv, from 'v-16418145218d8d7abdaabec46beb22ecffd2f5d1625.flv':
  Metadata:
    duration        : 14
    width           : 320
    height          : 240
    videodatarate   : 500
    framerate       : 25
    videocodecid    : 2
    audiodatarate   : 0
    audiosamplerate : 22050
    audiosamplesize : 16
    stereo          : true
    audiocodecid    : 2
    filesize        : 912970
  Duration: 00:00:13.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 576 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 320x240, 512 kb/s, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
File for preset 'iPod640' not found
```

But after doing a find, this is what I found.

```
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-ipod320.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-ipod640.ffpreset **** ITS HERE ******
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-lossless_fast.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-lossless_max.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-lossless_medium.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-lossless_slow.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-lossless_slower.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-lossless_ultrafast.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-main.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-max.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-medium.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-medium_firstpass.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-normal.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-placebo.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-placebo_firstpass.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-slow.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-slow_firstpass.ffpreset
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-slower.ffpreset
```

I alos tried with -vpre libx264-ipod640 and still no luck. I get preset libx264-ipod640 is not found.... Do i have to enable presets somehow? ffmpeg -- enable presets ? or something?

** EDIT: My ffmpeg version info **

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
FFmpeg 0.6.5
libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
```

Comment: Could it be a case problem ? `-vpre ipod640` instead of `-vpre iPod640`

Comment: No the uppercase lowercase wasn't my issue, turns out it was my versions' handling of order. The -vpre ipod640 had to be after -vpre fast. thank you for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution while experimenting. I had the wrong order of presets. It has to be the -vcodec then -vpre (speed) -vpre (presetprofile [aka ipod640])

Comment: What does (speed) stand for?? A certain preset mut be given.